# Is it possible to incrementally update added/edited datasets to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: data, fme-form, arcgis-online, google-maps-engine

My organization would like to run change detection and update our ArcGIS Online data incrementally.  Rather than re-uploading the entire data set every time we want to update the map.  We are a city government that has constant edits being made to all of our data.  We'd like to use FME to detect changes to the data and push these out to ArcGIS Online on a schedule.

We have been using Google Maps Engine to do this and are looking in to purchasing a license.  I'd hate to spend the money if there is a way to do this in AGOL that we are somehow missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than uploading the changes, an approach may be to edit the data directly in ArcGIS Online.

Within the My Content panel of ArcGIS Online, choose the Features you wish to make editable and choose the Edit button. Scroll down and enable the editing options:

[image]

This layer can now be edited in ArcMap (if you have an Editor or Advanced license) and online.

You can also interact with the service directly using the ArcGIS REST API, using an ApplyEdits operation - see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/fsedits.html

FME may have the means to do this directly - if not you may need to write something.

(FWIW, I haven't found an easy way to upload changes to ArcGIS Online - I've always needed to delete the service and re-upload, which is a pain.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a pain to do with our current workflows.  We are a large organization and it would cost a bit more than we're willing to invest to get everyone trained up.  I have a direct line with the "Software Products" team at ESRI and they seemed to be surprised that this was not possible as it is, in their words, "dead easy."  They said they would address this in their next dev meeting.  Hopefully that means it is on the way.  We ended up going with Google Maps Engine for visibility and ease of use, not to mention that their base maps are more up to date than ESRI's.

Comment: A direct line to Esri is always useful... Make sure you post back if you do find a resolution!